# Android :download file from server unable to decode stream

Tags: android, download

Im trying to download an image from a server ,using the android emulator. It seems that the download is working ,but i can't get the downloaded image .and i'm getting this error :

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

And this is the code that i used for :

```
public class DownloadActivity extends Activity {
// button to show progress dialog
Button btnShowProgress;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
ImageView my_image;
// Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
public static final int progress_bar_type = 0; 



 // File url to to download     
        private static String file_url = `"http://10.0.2.2:8080/TestAndroid/DownloadServlet/Desert.jpg";`

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // show progress bar button
    btnShowProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgressBar);
    // Image view to show image after downloading
    my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    /**
     * Show Progress bar click event
     * */
    btnShowProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // starting new Async Task
            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Showing Dialog
 * */
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setMax(100);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        return pDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to download file
 * */
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            // Output stream
          //  OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;
            long startTotalTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long passedTime =0;
            long previosTime=0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                long endtTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long passed;
                passedTime =endtTime - startTotalTime;
              //  passed=passedTime -previosTime ;
               // previosTime = passed ;

                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                Log.i("log_lenghtOfFile",lenghtOfFile+"" );
                Log.i("log_total",total+"" );
                Log.i("log_ourcentage",(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile)+"" );
                Log.i("log_passed_time",passedTime +"" );
                calculDebitdescendant( total, lenghtOfFile);
               // Log.i("log_Debit",passedTime +"" );
                // writing data to file
              //  output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            long endTotalTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.i("log_Total_passed_time",endTotalTime-startTotalTime +"" );

            // flushing output
          //  output.flush();

            // closing streams
         //   output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error***: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
    public void calculDebitdescendant(long bytesAvailable,long TotalSize){
        long bytesAvailable1 = bytesAvailable;
        long TotalSize1 = TotalSize;
        Log.i("bytesAvailable",bytesAvailable1  +"fonction");
        Log.i("log_ourcentage",(int)(((TotalSize1-bytesAvailable1 )*100)/TotalSize1 )+"% " );
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
   }

    /**
     * After completing background task
     * Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

        // Displaying downloaded image into image view
        // Reading image path from sdcard
        String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile.jpg";
        Log.i("imagePath", imagePath);
        // setting downloaded into image view
        my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
    }

}
```

}

PS :the sdcard of the emulator dont contain that image ,and i put all the permissions.
Please if someone knows the source of the error ,please tell me.Thank you.

Comment: Did you add the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in you `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: yes i did ,write and read too permissions.

Comment: This can happen if the external storage does not exists or not writable. [Here is a tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) about creating files in Android, there are methods examples for testing if the volume is available or not.

Comment: i tested the isExternalStorageWritable() and it reterned true ,what do think the problem is comming from ?

Comment: I Just looked at your code again and you actually never write the downloaded byte array into a file, you miss that part to make it work.

Comment: Ooo!! i put those lines in comment and i forgot them .Thank you @Thomas Bouron ,i'll edit the code ,if someone need it.

Answer (score 1):

I edited the code ,and i can download a picture from server to the sdcard of the emulator.I just enabled writing (i put them in comments )

```
public class DownloadActivity extends Activity {
// button to show progress dialog
Button btnShowProgress;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
ImageView my_image;
// Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
public static final int progress_bar_type = 0; 

// File url to to download     
   // private static String file_url = "http://192.168.1.106:8080/TestAndroid/DownloadServlet/Desert.jpg";
    private static String file_url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/TestAndroid/DownloadServlet/Desert.jpg";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // show progress bar button
    btnShowProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgressBar);
    // Image view to show image after downloading
    my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    /**
     * Show Progress bar click event
     * */
    btnShowProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // starting new Async Task
            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Showing Dialog
 * */
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setMax(100);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        return pDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to download file
 * */
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            // Output stream
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;
            long startTotalTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long passedTime =0;
            long previosTime=0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                long endtTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long passed;
                passedTime =endtTime - startTotalTime;
              //  passed=passedTime -previosTime ;
               // previosTime = passed ;

                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                Log.i("log_lenghtOfFile",lenghtOfFile+"" );
                Log.i("log_total",total+"" );
                Log.i("log_ourcentage",(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile)+"" );
                Log.i("log_passed_time",passedTime +"" );
                calculDebitdescendant( total, lenghtOfFile);
               // Log.i("log_Debit",passedTime +"" );
                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            long endTotalTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.i("log_Total_passed_time",endTotalTime-startTotalTime +"" );

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error***: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
    public void calculDebitdescendant(long bytesAvailable,long TotalSize){
        long bytesAvailable1 = bytesAvailable;
        long TotalSize1 = TotalSize;
        Log.i("bytesAvailable",bytesAvailable1  +"fonction");
        Log.i("log_ourcentage",(int)(((TotalSize1-bytesAvailable1 )*100)/TotalSize1 )+"% " );
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
   }

    /**
     * After completing background task
     * Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

        // Displaying downloaded image into image view
        // Reading image path from sdcard
        String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile.jpg";
        Log.i("imagePath", imagePath);
        Log.i("isExternalStorageWritable", isExternalStorageWritable() + "true" );
        // setting downloaded into image view
        my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
    }

}
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        Log.i("isExternalStorageWritable", "true" );
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}